# Meteor variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, meteor, each

I am fairly new to JavaScript and even newer to Meteor and am a little confused with what I think I know about variable scope and what the reality is. So I have this Meteor events helper:

```
Template.test.events({
  'click .selector': function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var someArray = [1,2,3,4];
   var someVariable = "jquery slector data";

   console.log(someVariable); //this works as expected

   someArray.each(function(index, el) {
     console.log(someVariable); //not defined?
   })
  }
})
```

I was under the impression that any variables declared outside my .each function would be available inside of it? However I am getting not defined. Is this a Meteor specific thing or JavaScript in general? Also, how would I make the variables accessible inside the .each function without making them global? I don't think defining my variable inside the .each loop would be ideal because that would mean multiple trips to the DOM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to use an `each()` method, which does not exist on `Array.prototype`. I believe you're looking for `Array.prototype.forEach()`. Underscore's `_.each(array, callback)` method would also work, and is more compatible with older browsers.

This should work:

```
Template.test.events({
  'click .selector': function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var someArray = [1,2,3,4];
    var someVariable = "jquery slector data";

    console.log(someVariable);

    someArray.forEach(function(val, index) {
      console.log(someVariable);
    });
  }
});
```

Or, for compatibility:

```
   _.each(someArray, function(val, index) {
     console.log(someVariable);
   })
```

I believe your confusion stems from using jQuery's `$.each()` method, which works differently from the native `forEach` and Underscore's `_.each()`. For one, jQuery has a different argument order (notice that I switched the order of the arguments in the code). In general, I'd recommend using Underscore for collection-related functions and use jQuery primarily for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I copied your example into my chrome console and it works. `console.log(someVariable)` is returning "jquery selector data".

However when I put the exact same code in my Meteor event handler I get "not defined" inside of the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Hmm, it's working fine for me. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/sbking/11239824) showing the code I used to test it. Could you post your exact full code?

Comment: Actually it does work! (still learning here)...what I was doing was pausing code execution in the forEach loop and manually typing  `someVariable` in the console and that was failing. However, if I included `someVariable` in the forEach loop prior to the event being executed it did indeed `console.log` the right data. I guess it makes sense based on Javascript's closures. Thanks again for your explanation.